# Aggregation strategy in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, bigdata, nosql

In my settings I have a stream of raw data, structured as JSONs. Each message is a JSON of a different format possibly. Some messages can be "joined" by some attributes, some cannot. I need to build some analytical data layer powered by Apache Spark to let easily querying that business data. This requires aggregation of messages into data units.  There are several options observed how to implement it:

1. Save raw messages to some database (maybe a relational db). Implement an aggregation job to turn raw data into Apache Parquet aggregates. These aggregates can be queried more easily, but an obvious disadvatange of this approach is that parquet data files are not document-oriented, that's why the data should be either stored "as is" which may bring insufficient performance or on the Parquet level the Domain can be split into several types of Parquet files  (this is more like a relational DB), thus doing "joins" on Apache Spark side. But I'm not sure which performance overheard the latter approach will give me and how good this practice is.
2. Maybe, there is another approach using some NoSQL db instead Parquet. Like MongoDB.

In both cases what I need is:

- minimal performance degrading
- convenient data layer for queries in which data is cached by Spark and not retrieved everytime

What are the most perspective options to implement my case ? Which storages should I most probably use ?

Comment: Sounds like Elasticsearch usecase

Comment: Apache Parquet is not document oriented but is pretty good for selects and joins. Maybe you could start with Spark + Parquet, perform joins - and get the idea of performance. Parquet performance looks really promising http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/04/benchmarking-apache-parquet-the-allstate-experience/